# How do I change LAN settings in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, settings, lan

I need to set automatic configuration script for LAN settings as shown in the attached image. The way I set it in Windows is by following the path: Control Panel--->Internet properties--->LAN Settings
I tried searching for it in Ubuntu 15.04 but was unable to find it. Please help me.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtVEu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to search "Network" and open it then click the "Network Proxy" to set the system wide proxy.

[Kindly check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhUOL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

### To configure a dynamic IP address

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

### Or configure a static IP

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.1.11
gateway 10.0.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.1.11
```

## DNS Entry:

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

## Restart Services

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

## Proxy Setting:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

it should like
   Acquire::http::proxy "http://10.0.1.1:8080/";